# Path integral of ${1\over z^{2}}$ around a circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was wondering how one would go about evaluating
$$\int_C \frac{1}{z^2}dz$$ when $C$ is a circle of positive radius centered at zero.  I suspected the answer should be $2\pi i$, but now I am not so sure.  Could I compare the circle's radius with that of the unit circle, make an annulus, split it into two simply connected regions and subtract the difference to get zero as the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you haven't specified any more advanced techniques, I'll assume you're still in the beginning of your complex analysis career.

You parametrize the circle via $z=re^{i\theta}, dz=ire^{i\theta}\,d\theta$ and then you get

$$\int_C{dz\over z^2}=\int_0^{2\pi}{ire^{i\theta}\over r^2e^{2i\theta}}\,d\theta$$

This is then

$${i\over r}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta=0$$

since $e^{-i\theta}$ is periodic with period $2\pi$.

Alternatively, if you remember your vector calculus, you can see that you are integrating $d\left(-{1\over z}\right)$ along a closed path, $\gamma:[a,b]\to \Bbb C$, and since ${1\over z}$ is a smooth path (i.e. a parametrization of your circle), you have that

$$\int_{\gamma}d\left(-{1\over z}\right)={-1\over \gamma(b)}-{-1\over \gamma(a)}=0$$

since $\gamma(b)=\gamma(a)$ and the formula is $\int_\gamma d(f) = f(\gamma(b))-f(\gamma(a))$. (you start and end at the same point).

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$ is a meromorphic function with a double pole in $z=0$ with residue zero, hence $\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dz $ for any contour $\gamma$ surrounding the origin is zero by the residue theorem.

Comment: I appreciate this comment, but I haven't learned the Residue theorem yet. I'm getting there, though.

Comment: I think you actually need to use this fact to prove the residue theorem.